# python formulas returning 0s

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I have basic formulas setup to recive numbers and then covert them but when running the program the converted formulas aren't calculating

```
dollars = 0
pounds = 0
tempF = 0
tempC = 0
globe = "\U0001F30D"


euros = dollars*.95
kilograms = pounds/2.2
tempF = tempC* 9/5+32 


print ("How many U.S dollars can you afford to spend on your trip?: ")
dollars = float(input())

print("How many pounds of chocoloate will you be buying?:")
pounds = float(input())

print("What is the tempature in degrees Celsius on the European news?:")
tempC = float(input())



print ("ITINERARY NOTES")
print ("------------------------------------------------------")

print (globe + " you have {:.2f} euros to spend." .format(euros))
print (globe + " Plan to buy {:.2f} of chocolate for family and friends".format(kilograms))
print (globe + " The tempature in Europe is {} degrees F, So dress appropriately.".format(tempF))
```

```
How many U.S dollars can you afford to spend on your trip?: 
100 
How many pounds of chocoloate will you be buying?:
5
What is the tempature in degrees Celsius on the European news?:
15

ITINERARY NOTES
------------------------------------------------------
 you have 0.00 euros to spend.
 Plan to buy 0.00 of chocolate for family and friends
 The temperature in Europe is 32.0 degrees F, So dress appropriately.
```

Comment: You need to calculate them after you've received the input. And no need to initialize everything with `0` beforehand.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych so how would I write that exactly

Comment: If you are new to procedural programming: You don't set up formulas as functional relationships. That would be defining a function. What you wrote is individual instructions on operations to performance: 1: Assign ```dollars``` the value 0. 2: Multiply the current value of ```dollars``` with 0.95. 3: Assign that result  to ```euros``` and so forth

Comment: thank you everyone for your help I'm still new to this and I'm doing this for my college course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How I would do it**

```py
def get_input():
    print ("How many U.S dollars can you afford to spend on your trip?: ")
    dollars = float(input())

    print("How many pounds of chocoloate will you be buying?:")
    pounds = float(input())

    print("What is the tempature in degrees Celsius on the European news?:")
    tempC = float(input())
    return [dollars, pounds, tempC]

def dollars_to_euros(dollars):
    return 0.95 * dollars

def pounds_to_kilograms(pounds):
    return pounds / 2.2

def tempC_to_tempF(tempC):
    return tempC * 9 / 5 + 32

globe = "\U0001F30D"

[dollars, pounds, tempC] = get_input()

#move formula calculation after receiving the input
euros = dollars_to_euros(dollars)
kilograms = pounds_to_kilograms(pounds)
tempF = tempC_to_tempF(tempC)


print ("ITINERARY NOTES")
print ("------------------------------------------------------")

print (globe + " you have {:.2f} euros to spend." .format(euros))
print (globe + " Plan to buy {:.2f} of chocolate for family and friends".format(kilograms))
print (globe + " The tempature in Europe is {} degrees F, So dress appropriately.".format(tempF))
```

**Minimal changes to your existing snippet to make it work:**

```
dollars = 0
pounds = 0
tempF = 0
tempC = 0
globe = "\U0001F30D"


print ("How many U.S dollars can you afford to spend on your trip?: ")
dollars = float(input())

print("How many pounds of chocoloate will you be buying?:")
pounds = float(input())

print("What is the tempature in degrees Celsius on the European news?:")
tempC = float(input())

#move formula calculation after receiving the input
euros = dollars*.95
kilograms = pounds/2.2
tempF = tempC* 9/5+32 


print ("ITINERARY NOTES")
print ("------------------------------------------------------")

print (globe + " you have {:.2f} euros to spend." .format(euros))
print (globe + " Plan to buy {:.2f} of chocolate for family and friends".format(kilograms))
print (globe + " The tempature in Europe is {} degrees F, So dress appropriately.".format(tempF))
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, there's no need to initialize variables with `0` before rewriting them with user-provided input.

Comment: Good point, I will add another snippet in how I would do it with good practices. I was trying to provide a working solution that has minimal changes to the original snippet. If we want to use all good practices, OP might not understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Try calculating the results after you `input` the data, not before that